# How to install forecast package of R in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I tried the following code for installation

```
>install.packages("forecast")
```

The error occurs like:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/root/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/RcppArmadillo’
ERROR: dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘RcppArmadillo’ are not available for package ‘forecast’
* removing ‘/root/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/forecast’

The downloaded packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpJqQfrh/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("forecast") :
installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("forecast") :
installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Can you install `Rcpp`, if not, what error does that give. Maybe you still need to install a C++ compiler? In ubuntu that is not standard...

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I have installed Rcpp still I am getting the error:make: *** [RcppArmadillo.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/root/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/RcppArmadillo’
ERROR: dependency ‘RcppArmadillo’ is not available for package ‘forecast’
 ‘/tmp/RtmpgSkOSs/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: What error do you get if you install RcppArmodillo?

Comment: when I am trying to install RcppArmodillo the following error occurs:Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘RcppArmodillo’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)

Comment: @Samraan This may seem an impertinent question, but did you spell it correctly? Just that if that's copied output, then you have an issue.

Comment: @sebastian-c yes the above errors are copied output....have any idea what type of issue it may be....

Comment: @Samraan It's spelled 'RcppArmadillo'.

Comment: @sebastian-c I had spelled correctly while installing this package....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem as:
First of all I have add the my CRAN  to the /etc/apt/sources.list. After that I executed the following command from my terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once the upgradation done successful the in R console give the command

```
install.packages("forecast")
```

This has resolved my problem. For details information regarding this you can visit cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu.

And I thanks to Dirk Eddelbuettel for his kind suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Instead of reposting as your answer what is already in the README I pointed to, you are supposed to 'accept' the correct or best answer (if you consider is suitable) by clicking on the tick mark only you as the person asking see. Additionally you can also up or downvote other answers. That's how SO is supposed to work.

Comment: @Samraan: Thanks for providing the exact information. It is a help to me too!

Answer (score 5):

Your R version is too old for the current versions of the packages which [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/package=forecast) depends upon.

You can try manually installing an older version of the [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/package=forecast) package by downloading from its [Archive/ section on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/forecast/).  A good bet would a version of about the same age as your R installation.

If you upgrade R to a current version, the Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, ... all install fine, and so will the newest version of forecast.  As you are on Ubuntu, it is actually extremely easy to get these newer version, [just read the README here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu) and add the apt repository information as described.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response.I tried to upgrade my R version as per instruction given in http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu.But still my R current version showing the older one i.e 2.14.1 (2011-12-22).Can You please tell me how I can upgrade my R to latest version.

Comment: I also tried to install the older version of it by downloading Archive section on CRAN but there is error :ERROR: dependency ‘RcppArmadillo’ is not available for package ‘forecast’. Again I am trying to install RcppArmadillo packages then there is error "dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available ".Can you please suggest me any alternative way to get out of this.

Comment: *If* your R is still 2.14.1 then you *did not* upgrade successfully.  Read the README again, contact a local admin if unclear.

Answer (score 2):

If updating CRAN doesn't work, you might be missing gcc-fortran. This is needed for quadprog, which is needed for timeseries which in turn is needed for the CRAN forecast package.

To install the gcc-fortran package on Arch Linux, execute:

```
# pacman -S gcc-fortran
```

To install the fortran compiler on Ubuntu, execute:

```
# apt-get install gfortran
```

Comment: This solution finally helped me on Arch. Thanks.